# What does Num Off Switch Containers mean in Yarn Resource Manager UI?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have an ETL job taking up lot of CPU and Memory and running for a long time. The first thing I observed while debugging is the following (from the job on the resource manager GUI)

- Num Node Local Containers (satisfied by) = 6
- Num Rack Local Containers (satisfied by) = 00
- Num Off Switch Containers (satisfied by) = 11367

We only have two racks. I need help with answering the following three questions

1. What is the meaning of Num Off Switch Containers?
2. How can I identify these "off switch" containers and which node(s) they ran on?
3. Does off switch containers contribute to slow job processing times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1 .What is the meaning of Num Off Switch Containers?**
The above case is of `off switch locality` by Delay Scheduler :-

```
                | router|
              +-----------+
             /             \
    +-----------+        +-----------+
    |rack switch|        |rack switch|
    +-----------+        +-----------+
    | data node |        | data node |
    +-----------+        +-----------+
    | data node |        | data node |
    +-----------+        +-----------+
```

It is the worst scenario of data locality (1.Node local 2. Rack local 3. off switch) by *Delay scheduler* and  the memory and vcores are getting allocated on different rack over the switch and much more higher bandwidths.

*The delay scheduler assigns the incoming task to an off-switch node which is located on a different rack to avoid task starvation*

For different schedulers in YARN config variables are there for node and rack threshold :-

*CAPACITY SCH* :-
With this property `yarn.scheduler.capacity.rack-locality-additional-delay` ,relaxing locality for off-switch container assignments is done.

capacity-scheduler.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>Number of missed scheduling opportunities after which the              CapacityScheduler attempts to schedule rack-local containers.
Typically this should be set to number of racks in the cluster, this
feature is disabled by default, set to -1.
 </description>
</property>
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4189 - JIRA for improvement
In case if cluster using Fair scheduler :-

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html

`yarn.scheduler.fair.locality.threshold.rack`

https://cs.stanford.edu/~matei/papers/2010/eurosys_delay_scheduling.pdf for delay scheduling.

**2.How can I identify these "off switch" containers and which node(s) they ran on?**

To view containers for an application I believe we need to go to particular application attempt via attempt id and there we can find conatainer and its node. I did not find any direct link to off switch container in RM ui

**3.Does off switch containers contribute to slow job processing times?**

Yes from above we can conclude ,the network overhead will slow job processing.